# Android Blend Modes

Tags: java, android, colors, blending

I am looking for a way to add more advanced blend modes to my program (ones that I could define myself). How would you suggest going about this with Android?

Setting pixels individually is too slow to be a viable solution.

Comment: This also needs to be a solution using the Canvas rendering system, not openGL.

Comment: Hi i asked a related question about just how many pixels android can draw and keep screen refresh speeds up. Just how many pixles are you drawing on each screeen and how fps are you getting ?

Comment: I don't really have a clue about the FPS, but I was attempting to set a 50x50 image multiple times(something around 40-50 times), and it was extremely slow. It's a smudge tool so the operation has to be applied to every few pixels along a drawn line.

Comment: It's bad because most android rendering methods are wrapped native methods which have far greater power to actually handle the rendering. Sorry I couldn't be more help to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I'm not sure this is supported. Using OpenGL as an example, the blending modes are defined by the OpenGL ES Spec, so that they can potentially be implemented in hardware. Adding your own blend function would be breaking the spec, not to mention incredibly slow, because it would have to act pixel by pixel.

I'm not so sure about canvas, but I believe that you can't do it there either, for similar reasons.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible even without openGL. PorterDuff should be the solution:

android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode

and

android.graphics.PorterDuff

Here is a very good example:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/Xfermodes.html

Comment: The problem is that I can't add a custom xFermode. For instance lighten,darken,saturate, etc.

Comment: @GuyNoir lighten and darken are already defined (see PorterDuff.Mode).

Answer (score -1):

Android supports a subset of OpenGL.  That would be the route to take if you're looking for speed.

Comment: This doesn't really address the question.